# need enough details to show a doctor map in profile

Tags: php, html, mysql

I just have a important question about my doctors website.

I have a table called "doctors" have columns like fullname,address,city,country,speciality,phone

And now i want to add the doctor location(using google map) , so my question is my address and city and country are enough to show doctor location in his profile , sometimes the address not exist in google map, or its better to add 2 columns in the doctors table called latitude and the other called longitude? What the better way? And what the big medical website use to show the doctor location.

Comment: That would certainly be better. But where are you going to get the latitude and longitude from if you can't look up the address in a map API like Google?

Comment: My guess is that most web sites that show maps use something like Google Maps and expect it to know all addresses.

Comment: Design questions like this are not really appropriate for SO. You need to ask questions about specific code, not general questions about how you should implement something.

Comment: since the case, that an adress would not be found on google maps would be quite seldom I'd just have a fallback if nothing returns from API. You could also make that desicion already when saving the data.